# Showing a graph algorithm

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphs, pause, tikz-node

I'd like to make a couple of slides on Beamer to show the way a graph algorithm works.

What I need is to be able to have in the beginning a graph. To be able to have an additional label of the nodes, outside of them, to be able to have weighted edges and to change the color of the edges. I have attached a picture below, as an example what for functionality I want my graph to have, but after some research, I didn't find a way to have all of those things.

Since in every step, I want to have a little change on the graph - to mark one node black, to change color of edge, to change outside label of node, one solution would be to copy the code on different frames. Is it possible to program it in a way, so it is easier and  on lesser frames?

[image: This is an example, how I want my graph to look like]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). You could add an [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of the static picture with `tikz` ([example of a graph](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/state-machine/)). In the next step you can add beamer commands like `\pause`, `\onslide` etc. to show it stepwise.

Comment: An example of an animated graph: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/prims-algorithm/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `label` for the text outside the states, and nodes to label the edges.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{%
  node distance=2cm,
  State/.style={%
    draw,circle,
    thick,
    color=black!60!green,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=10mm,
    fill=blue!40!green,
    text=white,
  },
  StateMark/.style={%
    State,
    fill=black},
  Edge/.style={%
    color=blue!40!green,
    very thick,
    -{Triangle[scale=1.1]},%% Try Latex instead oc Triangle
    text=black,
  },
  EdgeMark/.style={%
    Edge,
    color=blue!90!green,
    text=black,
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[StateMark,label=90:r] (S1) {$\infty$};
  \node[StateMark,label=90:s,right=of S1] (S2){0};
  \node[State,label=90:t,right=of S2] (S3){2};
  \node[State,label=90:x,right=of S3] (S4){6};
  %%
  \draw[Edge] (S1) -- node[above,pos=0.5]{5} (S2);
  \draw[Edge] (S1) to[bend right] node[below,pos=0.5]{5} (S3);%% Default bend = 30 degrees
  \draw[EdgeMark] (S2) -- node[above,pos=0.5]{2} (S3);
  \draw[EdgeMark] (S2) to[bend left=40] node[above,pos=0.5]{5} (S4);
  \draw[Edge] (S3) -- node[above,pos=0.5]{7} (S4);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To simplify the code the label text can be given as an input to `State` by changing the definition as

```
  State/.style={%
    draw,circle,
    thick,
    color=black!60!green,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=10mm,
    fill=blue!40!green,
    text=white,
    label=90:#1,
  },
  StateMark/.style={%
    State=#1,
    fill=black},
```

and then drawing the states as

```
  \node[StateMark=r] (S1) {$\infty$};
  \node[StateMark=s,right=of S1] (S2){0};
  \node[State=t,right=of S2] (S3){2};
  \node[State=x,right=of S3] (S4){6};
```